# Is there a clean way to put all instances of [number][number][alpha][alpha] in a string into a list?

Tags: c#

So take this string:

```
string fromUser = "a12 aa12, ab11, 13, 22 33 ac12";
```

I need to find all instances of [number][number][alpha][alpha], regardless of anything else.  Also, this data will be from the user, so it may be very messy (I tried to illustrate this in the example above).

This list would be the result:

```
aa12
ab11
ac12
```

I could do this in a "sloppy" way by just reviewing each character and keeping count of how many numeric and alpha characters in a row were found, but I was wondering if a more elegant solution is possible (maybe with some string functions that I am not aware of)?

How would you write this algorithm?

Comment: So you want everything from the user that starts with any 2 letters, then is followed by any two digits?

Comment: Have you met regular expressions? `(\d{2}[a-z]{2})` ignore case

Comment: @ZoharPeled OP is about to have their mind blown...

Comment: @maccettura yes, exactly!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Oddly enough we have pretty much an exact duplicate already

Comment: Agreed, closing as duplicate. The OP will have some research on what regexs *are* to do but that's not the worst outcome :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know what regular expressions are, but how would one place the result into a c# list?

Comment: @user7560542 The result of a regex match is already an array, so just `ToList`, or a number of other approaches. That's a separate question really

Comment: @user7560542 will the inputs be in a collection?  Your question sorta indicates that they might be in a comma delimited string.  Either way, once you have a _collection_ of strings you can filter that collection by whether or not each individual string is a match based on a Regex pattern

Comment: There seems a mismatch on what OP wants. The ask is number,number,alpha,alpa but the result is other way round. @user7560542. Confirm which one is it